# MAX HEAP heapify in C language

Tags: c, struct, heap

The problem is that my heapify func only heapifies once not the entire linked struct.

Sample: when I input, 1-2-3.

The result is: 3-2-1, correct:

but when I add four the result is: 3-4-2-1, wrong.

Should be: 4-3-2-1.

this is my heapify func:

```
void heapi(tree *heap, node *NODE,int COUNT){
int i,j,k,l,parent,parentcount,tempp;
node *temp;
temp=heap->root; 


   parentcount=COUNT/2;
if(parentcount<1){
    parentcount=1;
}
   if(COUNT==0){

   }

for(i=0;i<parentcount-1;i++){     
     temp=temp->next; 
 }

   parent=temp->data;

if(temp->next==NULL){

}
else if(temp->next->data > parent){
    tempp=temp->data;
       temp->data=NODE->data;
       heap->lastleaf->data=tempp;     
    }
else if(temp->next->next==NULL){

}
else if(temp->next->next->data > parent){
    tempp=temp->data;
    temp->data=NODE->data;
       heap->lastleaf->data=tempp;  
}


}
```

my structure is:

```
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct tree{
int count;
struct node *root;
struct node *lastleaf;
}tree;
```

Comment: Not that it helps, but building a binary heap is SO so much easier in a sequence container like an array, just fyi. Regardless, this problem was what *debuggers* were *made* for.  Stepping through the code, looking at variable contents, and seeing where they don't seem to be doing what you expect, is part of software engineering. Pretty important part too, as you'll probably spend half you're career staring at a debugger. Have you tried to do so here?

Comment: I actually am still an undergrad and studying computer engineering. This is one of our activity and i still can’t get the right codes in implementing heapify in data structure. We’re not allowed to use arrays bc it is so much easier.

Comment: In a heap, each node has two children. How does that correspond to your data structure?

Comment: the temp is the parent. the temp->next is the left child, the temp->next->next is the right child. my problem is if there more subtrees, the left child index is parent*2 and right child is (parent*2)-1 but i dont know how to implement it here in my struct

Comment: But `temp->next->next` is also the the left child of `temp->next`; it can't simultaneously be the right child of `temp`.  You need two pointers to create any sort of tree — or a way of calculating where the two children of a node are (which is where the array notation handles the issue).

Comment: Are you *sure* the instructor doesn't want you to use a binary tree for this? The code you're presenting looks like you're using a simple linked list which, frankly, is a *terrible* data structure for a heap. It requires all the math of an array-based solution, but without the array, so all the jumps to parents from children (and vice-versa) must be done iteratively, which is just a horrible design.

Comment: yup, it was a challenge activity. It's alrightI already solved it. Thanks!